# Laravel 5.3 Aggregate Sum with Accessor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
class Transaction extends Model{
    public function getTransSubtotalAttribute( $value ){
        return number_format($value, 2, '.', ',');
    }        
}
```

After I used an aggregate `sum`

```
<p><strong> Total Subtotal: {{ $trans->sum('trans_subtotal') }}</strong></p>
```

it changes to a whole number. For example 3366.00 the output is just 3. 
 I know this is from the `accessor` because If I remove the `accessor` I get the desired result which is 3366.00

Comment: Instead, try skipping the accessor, calculate the sum and then use number format.

Comment: How can I escape the accessor?

Comment: Can you post how you are trying to get data from your model? Based on that I will help you out.

Comment: `public function dateRange( $request ){
  $strtDt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->input("start_date")));
  $endDt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->input("end_date")));
  
  $endDt = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($endDt);
  return Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', [$strtDt, $endDt->addDay()])->get();

 }`     It doesn't format very well but that's my $trans

Comment: Final thing, can you post sample data you get from the function? So that I can write clear answer without any assumption?

Comment: ' $trans = $trans->dateRange($request);'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data on $trans variable. You can get the total by using laravel collections.

```
$total = collect($trans)->map(function($value){
    return $value->getOriginal('trans_subtotal');
})->sum();
```

Then, use number_format like

```
number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
```

Edit :

Add getSum to Model

```
public function getSum($trans, $field){ 
    $total = collect($trans)->map(function($value) use ($field) { 
        return $value->getOriginal($field); 
    })->sum(); 
    return number_format($total, 2, '.', ','); 
}
```

Then accessing it like

```
$value->getSum($trans, 'trans_subtotal');
```

Comment: In case someone encounter this  here is my complete solution. `public function getOriginalValue($trans, $field){

  $total = collect($trans)->map(function($value) use ($field) {
        return $value->getOriginal($field);
    })->sum();
  return number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
 }` `$subtotal = $this->getOriginalValue($trans, 'trans_subtotal');` credit to @Saravanan Sampathkumar.

Comment: Adding getOriginal to model and accessing it will override default getOriginal method in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model file